# JSON reponse with Spring Controllers in Jetty vs Tomcat

Tags: json, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, jetty

I am building a simple Spring MVC webapp and was developing on jetty. My controller binding used this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTRoutes.CREATE_DOC, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String getDoc
```

And returning a String from a JSONObject correctly resolves to JSON in my ajax response.

But using those same controllers, i deployed my gradle war to tomcat and my json came back wrapped as true strings.

So i changed my headers to use Map and that seems to fix things in both jetty and tomcat:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTRoutes.CREATE_DOC, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public  @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getDoc
```

I convert from the string to a map with this:

```
        HashMap<String, String> jsonResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if(claimFolder.has("error")){
            response.setStatus(500);
        }else{
            jsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(claimFolder.toString(), HashMap.class);
        }
        return jsonResponse;
```

My question is why this is nessesary?

Here's my jackson converter configuration:

```
<bean id="formConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />

<!-- add byte[] converter -->
<bean id="byteArrayConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
   <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/octet-stream" />
</bean>  

<!--  add in our JSON message converter -->
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- add in our plain string message converter -->
<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- Expose the authenticated handler to all beans that have been declared via annotation -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
</bean>
```

TL;DR: Why does jetty and tomcat return stringified JSON differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's absolutely normal for Spring content negotiation to translate a String object as a simple string without marshalling it to a JSON object. In order to serialize a java String object in JSON object you need to wrap it previously in some java class. For example:

```
QuestionStatus {

private String status;

public QuestionStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public getStatus() {
return status;
}
}
```

Hence you have to return in your `Controller` method not a String but QuestionStatus.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the Map object across all my endpoints and it seems to work correctly across Jetty and Tomcat. You right, i should probably create a POJO representing the response i'd expect from the DB.

Comment: Spring is not obvious sometimes, but thanks that it has wide community =)